# React - How handle mutiple parts website ? How scale a react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I just started react with the react-create-app.
I've made a small app, and know I'm having trouble splitting the website in different parts.

I'm making a website for an html5 game.
I made a quick prototype of the app with react (where players can see other connected players, start games, etc ..). For example, to get connected players, I just use axios to get data from a JAVA spring server.

But let say I want to create a welcome/login page before this app. [Like this](https://guardiansofatlas.com/)
This page page is just about "look a this cool game, register now ! ".

How should I do this with react ? Should I use React Router ?
And maybe later I want to add a DevBlog ? Maybe forums ? ... I don't want someone who want to see the devblog to download all assets from the forums.

How can I easly scale my little app ?

I'v lost myself, there seems to be so many ways ! Create a parallels node server ? Use server-side rendering ? NextsJS ? Redux ? Router ?

What's the best choice for someone who work alone ?

Comment: Suggesting you read on react router. Also, start splitting up pages and sections of pages into components. You'll see later on how easy it is to _compose_ the site out of reusable components. Think legos. You can ignore the server-side for now, just do API calls for your data.

Comment: +1 for react router. nextJS also has a router built in, but I've only made a small test project with it. redux is for state management and in my mind has little to do with directing people to different "parts" of a site.

Comment: Ok so I just should create different Router routes for all  different parts ?
But when should I care about server-side ?

Ok so redux seems to be something out of context, maybe an improvement that I should care about later ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `react-router` and something called asynchronous routing. Webpack lets you create multiple split points for each route using `require.ensure`.

Instead of having one giant js/css file you end up with multiple (as many as you wish) files that are downloaded asynchronously when user enters a certain route.

```
import { injectReducer } from '../../store/reducers'

export default (store) => ({
  path : 'forum',
  /*  Async getComponent is only invoked when route matches   */
  getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    /*  Webpack - use 'require.ensure' to create a split point
        and embed an async module loader (jsonp) when bundling   */
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      /*  Webpack - use require callback to define
          dependencies for bundling   */
      const Counter = require('./containers/ForumContainer').default
      const reducer = require('./modules/forum').default

      /*  Add the reducer to the store on key 'forum'  */
      injectReducer(store, { key: 'forum', reducer })

      /*  Return getComponent   */
      cb(null, Forum)

    /* Webpack named bundle   */
    }, 'forum')
  }
})
```

So with the above configuration when someone enters yourawesomepage.com/forum the necessary files get downloaded and also the reducer (from redux) responsible for forum gets injected.

[This](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit#application-structure) is a little starter-pack that has this feature out of the box.

Comment: Seems really interesting, webpack is still something a bit obscure for me.
But maybe I should drop create-app and try this !